# Editing Loop So It Targets Specific Tags?

Tags: categories, loop, tags

Confused on how to achieve this, but what I'm trying to do is load posts with the tag "reviews" in the loop on the homepage.

Index.php:

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        get_template_part( 'content-reviews', get_post_format() );
    ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php else : ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify the main query. Place this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function wpa71787_home_tag_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'reviews' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa71787_home_tag_query' );
```

You can set any valid parameters of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) with this method.

Edit, secondary query excluding tagged posts, use tag ID:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 42 ) ) );
while( $query->have_posts() ):
    $query->the_post();
    // loop stuff
endwhile;
```

Comment: i added `<?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tag=reviews' ); ?>` above `have_posts` but when I add the code ot the functions php it doesnt display anything.  I have 2 loops in the index file is that ok?

Comment: `add_action` does not work that way, you need to reference a function, see the example I provided. It has to go in `functions.php` because `pre_get_posts` happens before the template is loaded. If this is not your main loop, you should query directly for the posts you want by tag via [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: I have it working now, but I have 2 loops on the page that seem to be affected.  how do i display only the "reviews" tag in 1 loop while excluding it from the other?

Comment: Create a secondary query for other loops on the page, see edit above.

Comment: would that go in the functions.php?